# error in awk of shell script

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I am getting the below error ith my code.What is missing in it? My goal is to print 13.0.5.8 in $version

```
 #!/bin/ksh

 file="abc_def_APP_13.0.5.8"
  if echo "$file" | grep -E "abc_def_APP"; then
        echo "Version found: $file"

    version1=(echo $file |  awk -F_ '{print $NF}' | cut -d. -f1-3)

    version2=(echo $file | awk -F_ '{print $NF}' | cut -d. -f4-)

    echo $version1

    echo $version2

        version=$version$version2

        echo $version
 else
       echo "Version not found"
  fi
```

Please find below the error:

```
 ./version.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
./version.sh: line 7: ` version1=(echo $file |  awk -F_ '{print $NF}' | cut -d. -f1-3)'
./version.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
./version.sh: line 9: ` version2=(echo $file | awk -F_ '{print $NF}' | cut -d. -f4-)'



./version.sh: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can all be done in a single awk command and without additional cut command. Consider following command:

```
read version1 version2 < <(echo $file|awk -F "[_.]" '{
   printf("%s.%s.%s ", $4, $5, $6); printf("%s", $7);
   for (i=8; i<=NF; i++) printf(".%s", $i); print ""}')

echo "$version1 :: $version2"
```

#### OUTPUT

```
13.0.5 :: 8
```

Comment: I have a line in one more file with different version number. And I would like to replace this version number there.   `File1: location="/path/13.2.0/9/application1.war"`   How canI replace the `13.2.0/9` with $version1/$version2 which we obtained from above code. I have a code to get the old version number in file.  `VERSION=($(grep -r "location=.*war" /path/filename | awk  '{print ($1)}'| cut -f8- -d"/"|sed 's/.\{1\}$//'))`     This give me an output of olde version number 13.2.0/9

Comment: You can use this awk: `awk -v v1=$version1 -v v2=$version2 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="/"} {$3=v1; $4=v2;}'1 /path/filename`

Comment: It didnt change anything in the file. Will this awk supposed to replace the old version number with new one?

Comment: Yes, it will replace your old ver with the new one. Your file has this  content right: `location="/path/13.2.0/9/application1.war` ?

Comment: Its a very huge file with many application details. I want to replace the version number for one particular application at the line that `location="cc://view/blah/blah/blah/abc_def_APP/13.2.0/9/application1.war"` All the applications will have their own version numbers. Thats why in my above awk command I specifically did a grep for `location=.*application1.war`

Comment: Can I assume that old ver is `13.2.0/9` or it can be any other string also?

Comment: It will also be a string. Because we are replacing it with a new version number now. I want to do it dynamically every time version number changes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29617/discussion-between-anubhava-and-sravs448)

Comment: I am unable to open chat due to some policy issues...Do you want me to start a fresh thread for this?

Comment: Oh ok, since your new problem is very different from problem posted here, can you please create a new question with good explanation. Leave the question link here and I & other SO users will attend that promptly.

Comment: this is the link for new question   [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448814/shell-replace-a-particular-test-in-one-file

Comment: Thanks, let me try answering it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your backticks are missing `$` you need to fix the following two lines like so:

```
version1=$(echo $file |  awk -F_ '{print $NF}' | cut -d. -f1-3)

version2=$(echo $file | awk -F_ '{print $NF}' | cut -d. -f4-)
```

This will fix the syntactical errors. The following line doesn't make much sense as `$version` hasn't been initialize yet:

```
version=$version$version2
```

Did you mean:

```
version="${version1}.${version2}"
```

A side note you are using the `-E` option with `grep` but you aren't using any extended regexp features, in fact you are doing a fixed string string search so `-F` is more appropriate. You probably also want to use the `-q` option to suppress the output from `grep`.

Personally I would do:

```
file="abc_def_APP_13.0.5.8"

echo "$file" | awk '/abc_def_APP/{print "Version found: "$0;
                                  print $4,$5,$6;
                                  print $7;
                                  print $4,$5,$6,$7; 
                                  next}
                    {print "Version not found"}' FS='[_.]' OFS=.
```

If you just want the version number in the variable `version` then why not simply:

```
version=$(echo "$file" | grep -o '[0-9].*')
```

Comment: That seems rather fragile. How do you know `abc_def_APP` won't be `abc_def_foo_APP` later?

Comment: I don't, of course. I only know the information in the question given by the OP. My answer is the only one to point the reason for the scripts failure, my suggested `awk` solution is just a direct translation of what the OP already had so is only as fragile as his original solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for awk at all. Just trim every character before the last underscore, like so:

```
file="abc_def_APP_13.0.5.8"
version="${file##*_}"
echo "$version"
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073 for documentation on this technique, or see "parameter expansion" in bash's own docs.

To treat the last segment separately is also straightforward:

```
file="abc_def_APP_13.0.5.8"
version="${file##*_}"          # result: 13.0.5.8
version_end="${version##*.}"   # result: 8
version_start="${version%.*}"  # result: 13.0.5
echo "${version_start}/${version_end}" # result: 13.0.5/8
```

Because this happens internally to bash, without executing any external commands (such as awk), it should be considerably faster to execute than other approaches given.

Comment: This worked great, but I am looking to have my version variable with value `13.0.5/8`  Apologies as I was not clear in my question at beginning.How can I achieve it?

Comment: @sravs448 Updated appropriately.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth why should this be the accepted answer? The question was regarding the error the OP was seeing, the answer was the missing `$` in the backticks. This is a great alternative way to achieve the same goal but it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @sudo_O If someone is asking about why they can't carry water in a sieve, the best answer is to tell them how to use a bucket, not to suggest that they plug their sieve with clay.