# Shell: Subsitute a string between 2 Known strings

Tags: shell, replace, sed, awk

I wish to replace the contents of new_version varaiable (13.2.0/8) in between abc_def_APP and application1.war strings in file1

**Script :**

```
    #!/bin/ksh
   new_version="13.0.5/8"          
 old_version=($(grep -r "location=.*application1.war" /path/file1| awk '{print ($1)}'| cut -f8- -d"/"|sed 's/.\{1\}$//'))
   echo "$old_version" 'This gives me version number from file1 which needs to be replaced(13.2.0/9)
```

**File1 Contents:**

```
location="cc://view/blah/blah/blah/abc_def_APP/13.2.0/9/application1.war"
```

Comment: How would you know where in the file contents old version text is? I mean `13.2.0/9` can be a different string also isn't it?

Comment: Yes it can be any string.I need to replace the sting between `abc_def_APP` and `application1.war` with the new version number

Comment: But how would a script know where in the file contents this replacement should be made?

Comment: @anubhava: I have updated my answer in above comment. .The script needs to replace the sting between `abc_def_APP` and `application1.war` with the new version number.And the line also always starts with `location=`

Comment: @anubhava : can we do a regular expression match on `application1.war` and then replace ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following sed command to have your replacement:

```
sed -i.bak -r "s#^(.*/abc_def_APP/).*(/application1\.war.*)#\1$version1/$version2\2#" /path/file1
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk (for gensub()):

```
$ cat file
location="cc://view/blah/blah/blah/abc_def_APP/13.2.0/9/application1.war"

$ new_version="13.2.0/8" 

$ gawk -v nv="$new_version" '{$0=gensub(/^(location.*abc_def_APP\/).*(\/application1.war.*)/,"\\1" nv "\\2","")}1' file
location="cc://view/blah/blah/blah/abc_def_APP/13.2.0/8/application1.war"
```

The difference between this and a sed solution is that awk doesn't require you to jump through hoops due to your new_version variable containing a "/" (or any other character).